# Cycles imported whiskey glass not transparant

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, glass

I've just imported a whiskey glass from a file on Blendswap. When rendering it it just works fine, and looks like glass. When I import it to another scene, it's black untransparant glass? It's been a while since I've been "Blender-ing" so my Cycles experience isn't enough to know where the problem lies... Anyone with a lot of Cycles experience wanna take a look at it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just increase the number of total bounces in the scene (the other values are subdivisions of this main values).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I figured it had something to do with cycles settings. But just don't know enough about it... I'm still a Internal Render-user :/

Comment: Try also to abilitate the caustics: more noise but more accuracy in glass reflections and refractions, and please mark the answer as accepted!